# How do I pass specific ID to embedded YouTube player?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, youtube

**EDIT:** *I have came up with better solution. During the while loop I pass the id as an argument to a* `onclick` *function. BUT, now when I click any of the* `DIV`*s nothing happens. Can you tell where the problem is?? Thanks for the help.*

I have ran into a issue. I am trying to implement trailers. The way the user can watch them is by
clicking a div that should behave as a button using javascript / jQuery. The problem is I only want to have one embedded play so I don't need to recycle the code multiple times. But I can't figure out how to make the player play the trailer for the movies who's button just got clicked.  Below is the code and under it the summary of my request. Thanks for reading.

```
//Trailer links that got generated with a loop..
//EDIT: DIVs now contain the id as an attribute to a onClick function
<div class="trailer" onclick="playTrailer(M7lc1UVf-VE)">
    <p>WATCH TRAILER</p>
</div>

<div class="trailer" onclick="playTrailer(ksfj34ln-Xe)">
    <p>WATCH TRAILER</p>
</div>

<div class="trailer" onclick="playTrailer(rasdasdl-Xe)">
    <p>WATCH TRAILER</p>
</div>

//EDIT: added hidden DIV that should be displayed when the DIVs are clicked
<div id="trailer-box" style="display: none;">

    //EDIT: the play is now within the hidden DIV
    <div id="ytplayer"></div>

</div>

<script>
  function showMovie(id){
      $('.trailer-box').toggle(); //EDIT: newly added

      var tag = document.createElement('script');
      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

      var player;
      function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
          height: '390',
          width: '640',
          videoId: id
        });
      }
  }
</script>
```

I would like to know if there is a way for me to retrieve the value of `DIV` once it is clicked and pass it to the script's `videoId` field. If any of you know how this could be done, even if it means more adjustments please tell me. Thank you so much for reading and for your replies.

Comment: your working solution is here http://jsfiddle.net/j9M7E/12/ ...

Comment: I just tried it and it works! But I am so exhausted right now to try to actually implement it. Thank you so, so much! I will post an update tomorrow first thing. Sorry for the inconvenience, but I've been up for a really long time now. I hope you will still be around tomorrow to answer possible questions :). Thanks man.

Comment: Implemented & Working! Thank you so much. The only question I have is, how the hell does it work? What is the script inserting doing and why? Can you please explain?

Comment: it load script (youtube api), and when loading is complete call callback function (onYouTubeIframeAPIReady). more information you can found [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference)

Answer (score 0):

Should be something like

```
$('.watch').click (function (){
    player.loadVideoById($(this).attr ('id'));
});
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/j9M7E/6/)

[more info](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#loadVideoById)

Comment: Thank you very much, I have came up with a different solution, but it still isn't working. Can you please look at the EDIT in my post?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're not using jQuery, so:

You should use data attributes instead:

```
<div data-id="M7lc1UVf-VE" class="watch">
    <p>WATCH TRAILER for movie A</p>
</div>
```

Then:

```
var nodeList = document.querySelectorAll('.watch');

for (var i = 0; i < nodeList.length; i++) {
    nodeList[i].addEventListener('click', 
                    function(e){
                      showMovie(e.target.parentElement.getAttribute("data-id"));
                    }, 
                    false);
}

function showMovie(id){
  var tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  var player;
  function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
      height: '390',
      width: '640',
      videoId: id
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I have came up with a different solution and somewhat combined it with what you have suggested, but it still isn't working. Can you please look at the EDIT in my post?